# Bernoulli process in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
T=5;
p=0.3;
A=[randsample(T,1,'true'); zeros(T-1,1)]; %the first element of A is uniformly
                                          %randomly drawn from {1,...,T}
```

I don't know how to write this piece of code in Matlab:

```
%for t=2:T 
    %with probability p A(t)is A(t-1)+1 
    %with probability 1-p A(t) is uniformly randomly drawn from {1,...,T}   
%end
```

Comment: what is the problem in the first place? Do you get errors? If yes what is the stack trace?? Could you please put this information in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rand` to get uniformly distributed random variables, and `randi` to get random integers. Look up the documentation for them to see exactly how they work.

This code snippet should help you, it will go inside your `for` loop. I've used `rand()<p` to have something happen with probability `p`, as a random number from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 has a probability `p` of being less than `p`.

```
if rand()<p
    % this happens with probability p
    A(t)=A(t-1)+1
else
    % this happens with probability 1-p
    A(t)=randi(T)
end
```